# After pushing values into an array, array becomes a series of values having only one index

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, data-visualization

I pushed values after fetching an api as below into an array. 
After the pushing is done, the array suddenly becomes an array [], and became un-interable.

What did I do wrong and how can I make this array iterable that I could extract value by its inde x number like array[0]?

I used asynchronous function / Promises, to achieve this.

```
async function scrapingId(targetArtist){
    let APIRequest=await fetch(`https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?apikey=${myAPIkey}&query=${targetArtist}`)
                   .then(data=>{return data.json()});
    // console.log(APIRequest.resultsPage.results.artist[0].id);

    artistIds.push(APIRequest.resultsPage.results.artist[0].id);


    // console.log(artistIds)
}
```

Below is where the async function is executed.

```
.then((data)=>{

for (entity of data){
scrapingId(entity.artist);
};

return artistIds

}).then((data)=>{console.log(data)



})
```

The console.log(data) above spits out an array-like thing but I don't think that's a proper array which is iterable by its index number.

The output seems like an array but having 'key's which is index number of each entity.
[image]

Thank you inadvance.
Fullcode is attached here
https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/wvMwOxz?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `artistIds` before your `scrapingId(entity.artist)` is fetched, so in next `then` you get an empty array

you should return `promise` not an array of values

```
.then((data) => {
  const scrappingCalls = []
  for (const entity of data){
    scrappingCalls.push(scrapingId(entity.artist))
  }
  return Promise.all(scrappingCalls)
})
.then((data)=>{console.log(data)})
```

or even shorter it can be written

```
.then(data => Promise.all(data.map(({ artist }) => scrapingId(artist))))
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

UPDATE:
also change your function that it would return id

```
async function scrapingId(targetArtist){
  let APIRequest = await fetch(`https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?apikey=${myAPIkey}&query=${targetArtist}`)
    .then(data => data.json())

  const id = APIRequest.resultsPage.results.artist[0].id
  return id
}
```

Comment: Hi, It doesn't work it spits out a wierd array.
What I expected was something like [12,33,445,224,155,...]
But it ends up having [ duplicates of 'what I haved before']

Comment: @BS100, may be because your async function shoud return something, i changed it - please check

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you soooo much. why did my previous code spit out some weird array btw?

Comment: @BS100, i cant say exactly but it could not work correct because scrapingId didnt return anything